# Creating child table python (sqlite3)

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite3-python

I am parcing site with comics. First I am parcing catalog and creating `parent table` with names, urls of covers and status of comics.
After that I want to create `child tables` for each comic with list of chapters, release date of chapter and url of chapter.

Below is code that I am using. Unfortunately child tables are not created at all and I dont understand why. Please help what I missed.

```
import sqlite3
from time import sleep
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

connection = sqlite3.connect('parser_results.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Comics (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  cover TEXT NOT NULL,
  status TEXT NOT NULL
  )
''')

def get_url():
  for count in range(1,2):
    url = f"https://asuratoon.com/manga/?page={count}&order=update"
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    data_url = soup.find_all('div', class_='bsx')

    for comic in data_url:
      comic_url = comic.find('a').get('href')
      yield comic_url

for comic_url in get_url():
  response = requests.get(comic_url, headers=headers)
  sleep(3)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

  data_general = soup.find('div', class_='bixbox animefull')
  name = data_general.find('h1', class_='entry-title').text
  cover = data_general.find('img').get('src')
  status = data_general.find('div', class_='imptdt').text
  status = status.replace('Status ', '')
  cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Comics (name, cover, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (name, cover, status))
  connection.commit()
  
cursor.execute('SELECT id FROM Comics')
ids = cursor.fetchall()
for id in ids:
  cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ChildTable_%s (
                          id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                          chapter_name TEXT,
                          release_date TEXT,
                          chapter_url TEXT
                      )''' % (ids[0]))
  for comic_url in get_url():
    response = requests.get(comic_url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")  #lxml
    data = soup.find_all('div', class_='eph-num')
    for i in data:
      chapter_name = i.find('span', class_='chapternum').text
      release_date = i.find('span', class_='chapterdate').text
      chapter_url = i.find('a').get('href')
      cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ChildTable_%s (chapter_name, release_date, chapter_url) VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (chapter_name, release_date, chapter_url))
      connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

I tried code above and creation of child tables dont happen. I dont know which other options I have for my task.

Comment: Make sure to post actual code to reproduce the issue (for example, missing all imports).

Comment: In each iteration of `for id in ids` you are running `CREATE CHILD TABLE_{ids[0]}...` where `ids[0]` is going to be the same value every iteration. Did you mean `id` instead of `ids[0]`? More broadly speaking, and unrelated to you error, a single child table would be most appropriate. Creating a database obejct for every child instance is bad design. Just add a column in a single child table that holds the `id` of the child for the record you are writing. It may help with the issue you are facing in a round-about way too.

Comment: Thx, I created tables for each and it really eats a lot of resources, performance wise to have one child table is better I think. Will try to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reduced your code and used a dummy ids list, but if you change the child create sql command like my example it should work:

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('parser_results.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Comics (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  cover TEXT NOT NULL,
  status TEXT NOT NULL
  )
''')

ids = [(1,"urlOne"),(2,"urlTwo")]
for id in ids:
    child = "ChildTable_"+str(id[0])
    cursor.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [%s] (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        chapter_name TEXT,
        release_date TEXT,
        chapter_url TEXT
        );""" % child)
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: Yeah thx, I changed accoring to your suggestions and it worked